# Wear OS - Current Play Store version can't see my app but old play store version can see my app?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, wearables

I'm confused because my Wear OS app is not visible in the Play Store on my smartwatch if it is on the latest version but when I delete all updates for the Play Store, the old Play Store version can find my app under the point "Apps on your phone".

My Wear OS app is in a project with a smartphone app and the bundle that includes both is uploaded to the Google Play Console as an Internal Test. The phone, with that my smartwatch, is connected, is registered as a Tester for this Internal Test, and on my phone when I open the Play Store and go to my app, it is shown that I'm a Tester. That seems correct so far.
The only problem is that I can't my Wear OS app at the Play Store if it is up to date...

Some other apps on my phone seem to have the same problem because at the newest Play Store Version many Apps from my phone are not shown. But when I delete the Play Store Updates, I can see many other Apps from my phone...

I hope my request is not too confusing.

Thank's to everyone in advance!

Comment: F.M. have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem: my app "wear" module is bundled with the "mobile" module output, so when I generate a mobile apk, it is installed on the phone, and if the watch is paired with the phone, the app also shows on the watch's OLD play store. If I let it update to the NEW play store, it doesn't show my app in the watch anymore.

Comment: Hey Peter, I didn't find a correct solution for developing.

Comment: Hey Peter, I didn't find a correct solution for development. During development I put the wear app directly on the watch by using android studio and/or by using the "downgrad" way with the play store, in case you put it already on your phone with the play store. For getting the Wear OS App direkt from the play store for testing or production, I had to put some information about the Wear OS app in my app's store listing. Here is a guideline what you have to do: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-wear#opt_in

Comment: The guideline is confusing and seams a little bit to be random. They want you to mention the words "Wear OS" in your app listing. I just but this word to the bottom of my info text without any context. And, togehter with the other things they want, and I uploaded my wear app to the play store, it was also visible on the "updated" playstore